# Deezer iOS SDK - Play specific track from radio

Tags: ios, objective-c, deezer

I'm currently working with Deezer SDK to play a radio from deezer in my app.
Is possible to play a radio even if the user has not authorized my app.

Is there a way to play a specific track from a Radio?

I'm following [this guide](https://developers.deezer.com/sdk/ios#player) but it seems that this was possible in the old Sdk but not in the new.
In the old sdk there were also more Delegate methods such as

```
- (void)player:(PlayerFactory *)player timeChanged:(long)time
```

But my main goal would be to play a track from a radio, in order to be sure to not play the same track two times in a row.

Is there someone that knows how to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to play a radio even you aren't connected if you want you can take a look here :

- https://developers.deezer.com/sdk/ios#player
- At the section « Play a
  radio without user connected (New Api)

Of course you can play a specific track from a radio,
a radio is like, a playlist or an album, it's a DZRObjectList.

From your DZRObjectList, you can call :

```
- (void)allObjectsWithManager:(DZRRequestManager *)manager callback:(void (^)(NSArray *objs, NSError *error))callback;
```

Every object should be a track, so you can achieve your goal by making a check directly on the array.

Best Regards,

**EDIT**

This is an example :

```
DZRRadio *yourDZRRadio;
DZRRequestManager *manager = [[DZRRequestManager defaultManager] subManager];
[yourDZRRadio valueForKey:@"tracks" withRequestManager:manager callback:^(DZRObjectList *objectList, NSError *error) {
    if (objectList != nil) {
        [objectList allObjectsWithManager:manager callback:^(NSArray *tracks, NSError *error) {
            /*
             *  Here you have tracks from your radio so you can send it to your player :)
             */
        }];
    } else {

    }
}];
```

Comment: Can you please write me an example? What you wrote seems intersting but I did not understand how to get a dzrObjectlist from a radio and play a single track

Comment: Thank you so much. It works, kind of..In this way there is the limit of the 30s if the user is not logged in on deezer, right?

Comment: @allemattio if you want to play a track in your own player the limit is 30s. If you use DZRPlayer you have no limit if the user is logged. You can check the sample of the SDK, if you want an example.